# Write efficient queries with the OutlookServicesClient

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I am using the [Office 365 Mail API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations) and my goal is to get the **total number** of email messages a user **sent** (1.) and **received** (2.) ***today***.

Todo this, I first created and tried and run some queries in the [Office 365 API Playground](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net):

1. `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages?$filter=sentdatetime%20ge%202015-12-10T08:00:00.000Z&$select=Subject,CreatedDateTime,ToRecipients`
2. `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$count=true&$filter=receiveddatetime%20ge%202015-12-09T10:00:00.000Z&$select=Subject,CreatedDateTime,ToRecipients`

Now, I am struggling with writing these queries with the OutlookServicesClient API. I didn't find many examples, which go beyond very simple queries... What I have so far:

1. `var mailResults = await client.Me.MailFolders.Where(f => f.DisplayName == "Sent Items").ExecuteAsync();` This does not yet return **just the messages** and filter them for the **current date**.
2. `var mailResults = await client.Me.Messages.Where(m => m.ReceivedDateTime.Value == date.UtcDateTime).ExecuteAsync();` Does **not return any results**, even though I received many emails. Further, I'd like to exclude emails which I received in folders 'Cluster', 'Deleted Items' and 'Junk Email'.

Generally, I am not sure if it's a good idea to filter with English folder names, as I would need to change the code for other languages. Are there special Ids for the special Outlook folders, such as Sent Items, Junk Email, Cluster, etc.?

Additionally, to solve my two requests, I could just fetch all emails and handle the filtering by myself, but that's not efficient and the API already supports filtering (as can be seen in the raw requests), I am just not sure how to write them with the [OutlookServicesClient API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/2.0.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the `OutlookServicesClient` uses LINQ to build it's queries, so you'd need to use the `Where` method to build a `$filter` query parameter. If you wanted to get all messages received today, for example, you would do something like:

```
DateTimeOffset startOfDay = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime();

client.Me.Messages.Where(m => m.ReceivedDateTime >= startOfDay).ExecuteAsync();
```

On your questions:

1. Don't filter by the name of the folder. The API has constant folder
   IDs for Inbox, Deleted Items, Sent Items, and Drafts. So to get the
   Sent Items folder you would do:

   ```
   client.Me.MailFolders.GetById("SentItems")
   ```
2. Your query `Where(m => m.ReceivedDateTime.Value ==
   date.UtcDateTime)` wouldn't return values because you're testing that the datetime value is **equal** to a constant, which is pretty much never going to return a result. The comparison goes down to the seconds level, so unless you have messages received **exactly** at the date and time in your `date` variable, you'll get no matches.

I wrote up some queries that I think match your intent:

```
DateTimeOffset startOfDay = DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime();

var receivedMessages = await client.Me.Messages
  // $orderby=ReceivedDateTime desc
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.ReceivedDateTime)
  // $filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2015-12-11T05:00:00Z
  .Where(m => m.ReceivedDateTime >= startOfDay)
  // $top=10
  .Take(10)
  // $select=Subject,ReceivedDateTime,From
  .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From })
  .ExecuteAsync();

string resultMessage = "";
foreach (var message in receivedMessages.CurrentPage)
{
  resultMessage += "Received: " + message.ReceivedDateTime.ToString() + " from " + message.From.EmailAddress.Address
                   + ": " + message.Subject + "\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(resultMessage, "Received messages");

var sentMessages = await client.Me.MailFolders.GetById("SentItems").Messages
  // $orderby=SentDateTime desc
  .OrderByDescending(m => m.SentDateTime)
  // $filter=SentDateTime ge 2015-12-11T05:00:00Z
  .Where(m => m.SentDateTime >= startOfDay)
  // $top=10
  .Take(10)
  // $select=Subject,ReceivedDateTime,From
  .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.SentDateTime, m.ToRecipients })
  .ExecuteAsync();

resultMessage = "";
foreach (var message in sentMessages.CurrentPage)
{
  resultMessage += "Sent: " + message.SentDateTime.ToString() + " to " + message.ToRecipients.Count
                 + " recipients: " + message.Subject + "\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(resultMessage, "Sent messages");
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much Jason! I didn't know about the GetById(..) method and the date was a stupid mistake from my side. Is it also possible to just run a count (i.e. # messages in the inbox)? And, if I want to get a count of **all** messages sent on a day, I could change the Take method to 10000 or something. Is there a more efficient/faster way to do this? (I also noticed the maximum might be 500 per Page?) Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do a filtered count in the .NET library. There is a `CountAsync` method off of `client.Me.Messages`, but it doesn't apply once you start adding `Where` or `Select` or anything like that. I'll check with the devs and see if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I've also had the same findings. Thanks for checking!

Comment: No problem. I just checked and it isn't doable with the library as it currently stands. So you would want to implement paging and do that to make sure you get all the results.

Comment: Thanks for checking! I'll do that. Do you know if this is on the roadmap? Is 500 the highest amount of items I can get on one page (with Take(500)? Or would you suggest me to use the default (10)?

Comment: hi @Jason Johnston I just realized that the "receivedMessages" also contains emails I've sent, even though we check witht he REceivedDateTime. Do you have an idea why that is and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `.Me.Messages` accesses all your folders, including Sent Items. Pull from just the folder you want instead.

Comment: Thanks Jason! As I want to get 'all' emails received, what I am doing now is looking at Me.Messages and subtracting the sent emails and emails in the draft/junk/trash folder :)